# Whats wrong with mysql_num_rows? It is Returning errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

I used this series and I'm up to this video and `mysql_num_rows` has been pissing me off ever since the start.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HP75yyjHgTg
i have easily spent 5 hours simply trying to fix all these `mysql_num_rows` errors.
At the Moment I'm doing profile page and I'm getting an error.
The Error is:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/ztechrel/public_html/TESTING/blarg/REMAKE/profile.php on line 8 (line one is the mysql_num_rows part)

The Code in profile.php is:

```
<?php include("inc/incfiles/header.php"); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);

    if(ctype_alnum($username))   //check user exists
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username,first_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($check)===1) 
    {
        $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
        $username = $get['username'];
        $firstname = $get['first_name'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h2>User Does Not Exist</h2>";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

is there a way i can fix this?
Or does anyone know another way i can write this?
I wouldn't be surprised he uses `mysql_num_rows` again, is there something i can use instead which is easy to implement?
If you need any other info just ask.

Comment: There's something wrong with the query possibly - type `echo mysql_error()`. Also, I would highly recommend you don't use the `mysql_` functions as they will be deprecated after PHP5.5

Comment: This tutorial is extremely outdated.... use tutorials that teach using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements rather than MySQL

Comment: what functions could i use instead?

Comment: do you reccomend any tutorials which could be helpful for making a social network with similar features like facebook? eg. news feed, friends, profiles and so on?

Comment: It's like the error says: `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given`. So your `mysql_query()` is not doing its job, it's returning null. Probably you didn't connect to your database. Try changing it to `mysql_query("...your query...") or die(mysql_error());` to get the good error message.

Comment: If the username is not alphanumeric, you're not setting `$check` at all.

Answer (score 0):

use this for checking error in your query

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
if(ctype_alnum($username)) {
    //check user exists
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT username,first_name FROM users 
    WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($check)===1){
        $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
        $username = $get['username'];
        $firstname = $get['first_name'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h2>User Does Not Exist</h2>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are capture errors from PHP.

It might be the previous statement mysql_query is not executed and hence result is not set.

Try with below if mysql_query is executing properly or note

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT username,first_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'")  or die(mysql_error()."<br>".$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

This means your query returns nothing. Put echo for your query and display it in browser. Then copy the query and run it in phpmyadmin or mysql query browser or some other mysql editor. Try to find whether `$username` has correct value or any field name is wrong in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure variable `$username` is not empty., `ctype_alnum` is returning false. So `$query` is empty.

```
<?php include("inc/incfiles/header.php"); ?>
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['u'])) {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);

        if ($username != "" && if(ctype_alnum($username))) {
            $check = mysql_query("SELECT username,first_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($check)===1) 
            {
                $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
                $username = $get['username'];
                $firstname = $get['first_name'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<h2>User Does Not Exist</h2>";
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

?>
```